# Event for mouse leaving a NSWindow instance

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nswindow, appkit

Is there a mechanism for detecting when the mouse leaves the active `NSWindow` bounds?

I've already tried overriding the `mouseMoved:` method, but that is not called when the mouse is outside the `NSWindow` bounds.

Comment: [`NSTrackingArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingarea?language=objc) might be the key. It has a `mouseExited:` method and it can work even when `NSApp` is inactive. I'll try it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best is to use [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingarea?language=objc)

```
- (void)configureTrackingArea
{
    NSRect trackingRect = self.window.contentView.frame
    NSTrackingAreaOptions trackingOptions = NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;
    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:trackingRect options:trackingOptions owner:self userInfo:nil];

    NSView *contentView = [[self window] contentView];
    [contentView addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}


- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [[self window] addChildWindow:[self previewWindow] ordered:NSWindowAbove];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self hidePreviewWindow];
}
```